# applying the paragraph style to last cell of current table in InDesign script

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

How can I applying the paragraph style to last cell of current table in InDesign script.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument,
table = doc.stories[1].tables[0];
var rc= table.rows.count;
table.rows[rc-1].cells[2].text.applyedParagraphStyle="t1";
```

Comment: Replace your last line of code with the following: `table.cells[table.cells.length -1].texts[0].appliedParagraphStyle = 't1';` - Note: line #3 in your example, i.e. `var rc= table.rows.count;`, then becomes redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Texts is a collection of text items in the cell. You can apply paragraph style to collection or you need to reference an item in the collection

Try this:

```
table.rows[rc-1].cells[2].texts.applyedParagraphStyle="t1";
```

or this:

```
table.rows[rc-1].cells[2].text[0].appliedParagraphStyle="t1";
```